# Unable to process a paiement in paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal-sandbox

Il am getting an error in paypal sandbox when trying to make a paiement using the account created in PaypalDevelopper (type personal).

- I connected to PaypalDevelopper using my real paypal account.
- I had a business and a personal account auto-created.
- I upgraded the business to business-pro because it seemes the only way to be able to create paiements butons.
- I then created a button under the business-pro sandbox account, clicked on it in my website, and tried to pay using my personal sandbox account. I then have this error.
- I tried creating new sandbox accounts, and still had the same problem.

I live in France and configured my state as "France".
My sandbox mails seem to be confirmed, as when I try to confirm those in sandbox paypal it says that they are already confirmed.

Thank you for any help.

Here is the error that appears in the paypal paiement window.

```
Rapids::Exception (N6Rapids5Tools13PimpExceptionE): Pimp RC: 0
```

Failure log: Use of pimp_rc (4814), Use of pimp_rc (3013), Use of pimp_rc (4814), Use of pimp_rc (3174), Use of pimp_rc (7184), Use of pimp_rc (14816), Use of pimp_rc (9449), Use of pimp_rc (9445), Use of pimp_rc (4814), Use of pimp_rc (3507), Use of pimp_rc (4001), Use of pimp_rc (4002), Use of pimp_rc (3778), Use of pimp_rc (4007), Use of pimp_rc (4020), Use of pimp_rc (7003), Use of pimp_rc (3583), Use of pimp_rc (3051), Use of pimp_rc (3001), Use of pimp_rc (3021), Use of pimp_rc (3242), Use of pimp_rc (3165), Use of pimp_rc (3101), Use of pimp_rc (3085), Use of pimp_rc (3209), Use of pimp_rc (3174), Use of pimp_rc (3043), Use of pimp_rc (3241), Use of pimp_rc (3082), Use of pimp_rc (3129), Use of pimp_rc (3567), Use of pimp_rc (3235), Use of pimp_rc (3236), Use of pimp_rc (3508), Use of pimp_rc (3507), Use of pimp_rc (3531), Use of pimp_rc (3514), Use of pimp_rc (3124), Use of pimp_rc (3047), Use of pimp_rc (3224), Use of pimp_rc (3093), Use of pimp_rc (3253), Use of pimp_rc (3254), Use of pimp_rc (3083), Use of pimp_rc (3137), Use of pimp_rc (3256), Use of pimp_rc (14268), Use of pimp_rc (14267), Use of pimp_rc (14266), Use of pimp_rc (14269), Use of pimp_rc (14264), Use of pimp_rc (14265), Use of pimp_rc (14244), Use of pimp_rc (3084), Use of pimp_rc (3254), Use of pimp_rc (3083), Use of pimp_rc (3137), Use of pimp_rc (3070), Use of pimp_rc (3141), Use of pimp_rc (3198), Use of pimp_rc (3011), Use of pimp_rc (10021), Use of pimp_rc (3199), Use of pimp_rc (3015), Use of pimp_rc (3014), Use of pimp_rc (3200), Use of pimp_rc (3257), Use of pimp_rc (3012), Use of pimp_rc (3141), Use of pimp_rc (3535), Use of pimp_rc (3504), Use of pimp_rc (10022), Use of pimp_rc (6702), Use of pimp_rc (3001), Use of pimp_rc (3120), Use of pimp_rc (3517), Use of pimp_rc (3531), Use of pimp_rc (3201), Use of pimp_rc (3803), Use of pimp_rc (6834), Use of pimp_rc (3807), Use of pimp_rc (3808), Use of pimp_rc (3810), Use of pimp_rc (3812), Use of pimp_rc (3809), Use of pimp_rc (3805), Use of pimp_rc (2002), Use of pimp_rc (3177), Use of pimp_rc (3051), Use of pimp_rc (3510), Use of pimp_rc (4003), Use of pimp_rc (3013), Use of pimp_rc (4011), Use of pimp_rc (3300), Use of pimp_rc (3286), Use of pimp_rc (6681), Use of pimp_rc (14605), Use of pimp_rc (10361), Use of pimp_rc (14353), Use of pimp_rc (14817), Use of pimp_rc (4002), Use of pimp_rc (2001), Use of pimp_rc (4001), Use of pimp_rc (11045), Use of pimp_rc (3593), Use of pimp_rc (4071), Use of pimp_rc (3514), Use of pimp_rc (4022), Use of pimp_rc (4011), Use of pimp_rc (9500), Use of pimp_rc (9501), Use of pimp_rc (11729), Use of pimp_rc (11728), Use of pimp_rc (4001), Use of pimp_rc (9501), Use of pimp_rc (14774), Use of pimp_rc (14774), Use of pimp_rc (3304), Use of pimp_rc (3304) Backtrace: PPException::PPException(String const&) Rapids::Tools::PimpException::PimpException() Rapids::Flows::Unity::StateUnityAnalyzeTransaction::execute(Rapids::CGIVars const&) Rapids::DecoratedState::execute(Rapids::CGIVars const&) Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::handle_execute(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate const&, Rapids::TransitionRegistry const&, Rapids::State*, String const&, String const&, unsigned long long) Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::process_states(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate const&, Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::ProcessStates, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&, Rapids::TransitionEdge const*) Riprap::RiprapRapidsGenericFlow::flow_continue_post(Riprap::WebAppContextOrnate const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::call_rapids(Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::RapidsFlowFactory const&, Riprap::DispatchAction const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, String const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::dispatch_loop(Riprap::EPRegistry const&, Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::DispatchAction&, Riprap::WebAppReturn&, String const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::dispatch_wrapper(OutputStream&, Riprap::EPRegistry const&, Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, String const&, bool const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::entry_point(HTTPInterface&, Riprap::CGIVars&, OutputStream&, String const&, String const&) main

Une erreur s'est produite.

Retour à la page d'accueil

Comment: I have created a simple business account + created a personal form not using the paypal button creation tool and it works.

But using this personal form with the business-pro account gets the sames error

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work :

- Using a business account and not upgrading to business-pro. I still don't understand why it won't work with a business-pro account, but I don't bother.
- Finding where the buy-button creating tool is hidden in the sandbox business account. It was a long and adventurous trip !